# onclick / anchor tag- javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me on how to add anchor link/ onclick to a datarow

```
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
          dataRow1 = dataRow.insertCell(0);
          record =  document.createTextNode(returnedValues[i].Name);   
          dataRow1.appendChild(record);
        }
```

Comment: show your HTML and dom structure

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, I assume this might be helpful:

```
// Create anchor tag
const a = document.createElement('a');

// Add link
a.href = 'http://yourlink.com';

// Add Text
a.innerText = 'Custom Link';

// `dataRow` should be a HTML Element
dataRow.appendChild(a);
```